# Close del dialog de angular material - afterclosed(), backdropClick()

Tags: angular, material

Estimados tengo este dialog, que funciona correcto, pero el close() correctamente solo funciona con el botón click, y me recuerda un data que envió, el problema surge que al cerrar con el fondo del dialog cierra pero no envía o recuérda la data como lo hace con el botón estoy intentando hacer esto pero no funciona o no es correcto, como puedo hacer que el close del backdropClick, también envié la data del afterClosed(). espero que quede claro gracias.

```js
openDialog() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(ModalCouponsComponent, {
      panelClass: 'modal-class-coupon',
      disableClose: false,
    });
   
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((data) => {
        this.validarCodigoDeRespuestaDeCuponesRedimidos(data.data)
    })

    dialogRef.backdropClick().subscribe((data) => {
      console.log(data, 'data backdrop')
      this.validarCodigoDeRespuestaDeCuponesRedimidos(data.data);
    })
  }
```

Comment: me canse de buscar información y ejemplos se ve que a nadie le ha pasado algo parecido?

Comment: es mas fácil si sólo pones esto
.cdk-overlay-dark-backdrop { pointer-events: none !important;}

Answer (score 0):

te recomendaria que mejor deshabilites la opcion de dar clic en el backdropClick

lo puedes deshabilitar mandando como segundo argumento el disableClose en true

```
openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(tuComponente, { disableClose: true });
 }
```